# How to remove ON DELETE CASCADE convention for all tables with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

All foreign columns with Entity Framework are always placed with ON DELETE CASCADE. I want to remove that from all the tables, how could I do that?

I tried to do this in class with DbContext:

```
  protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
  {
    configurationBuilder.Conventions.Remove<CascadeDeleteConvention>();
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to create a migration and check if it works?

Comment: @sa-es-ir 
Yes I tried it, I don't know how it chooses which one, but it only removed the on delete cascade from the first table that had a foreign one, I don't know if it's a coincidence or whatever the reason.